# action.devices.traits.Modes - anyone implemented this?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

i've implemented a Smart Home app on Google, and now want to implement the n-way Modes trait for some switch types. 
my JSON response seems to mirror that of the example, and discovery works, but i can't interact with the switch using the mode examples (JSON not complete) - anyone got any idea what i'm missing?

```
    "attributes": {
           "availableModes": [{
                 "name": "Control",
                 "name_values": [{
                   "name_synonym": ["control", "mode"],
                   "lang": "en"
                    }],
                 "settings": [{
                  "setting_name": "Off",
                  "setting_values": [{
                    "setting_synonym": [ "Off"],
                    "lang": "en"
                    }]
                 },{
                  "setting_name": "Level1",
                  "setting_values": [{
                    "setting_synonym": ["Level1"],
                    "lang": "en"
                    }]
               }],
                 "ordered": false
              }]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/modes), custom names for modes and toggles do not work yet.

"Currently, you must submit names to us so we can add support for them."

Comment: Ok - so can Google provide a list of names that do work, and also can the documentation be updated to let people know how to submit custom names?

Comment: Right now there's no documentation of existing modes. Right now there's not a great pathway to submit custom names, but you can file an issue on the sample app: https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-smart-home-nodejs/issues/new